# RadioButtonList need to simulate RenderWhenDataEmpty in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

The link below from MSDN show a property that seemed to get added in ASP.NET 4.5

[RadioButtonList.RenderWhenDataEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.renderwhendataempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I need this functionality in ASP.NET version 4.0, so I wondering if anyone knows of a quick and dirty way to do such thing.  I know I can check the dataset that I am binding to if it is empty and then render something else, but I really want to get all the properties of the radio button to render with just no option.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of output in the HTML do you want? Just radio button with no value next to it?

Comment: The radio button list is rendered either as a table as a div.  I want the structure to render for an empty list so that I can populate client side

Comment: Can you add a default value and then remove that client side?

Comment: That worked well actually.  Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Creating the answer for the casual observers:*

Basically you need the HTML empty structure to be rendered. Otherwise your client side code can't populate the options.

Like you said .NET 4.5 introduced the `RenderWhenDataEmpty` option. If you can't upgrade I suggest adding a default value and then remove that on the client side as you populate it.